# Ajax request depending on first (then.)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to use the first function to check whether the item exists and if I can add the item to the PHP $_session.

I want to have a MAX of 3 items in a $_Session and if the item exists in the session it will return 1. so that the favorite function can update the information in the session which belongs to the ID of the item. The $_Session has a multi-dimensional array which holds the id of the item with an array of properties of the item. Later on, when the sidebar is opened I have an ajax call requestion all the relevant information in the session which is then queried to my SQL to get the most up to date information. PHP then cleans up the code and sends it back as JSON, and Javascript parses it to place it in the sidebar.

I have been trying to figure out how to do this with the ".then" option in JavaScript but I'm not getting any further with it.

(I added some comments in the code to explain what it does and what it should get back from PHP / $_SESSION )

```
function favoriteNr(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var door_param = gup( 'name' );
    xhr.open('POST', '/nr_check.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHtppRequest');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            var result = xhr.responseText;
            console.log('Result: ' + result);
            var favoriteNr = result; // returns a number, between 0 to 2 it should let the other function run otherwhise it should run the alert function
        }
    };
    xhr.send("door=" + door_param); }

function favorite(){
    var parent = this.parentElement;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var door_param = gup( 'name' ); //Gets the value "name" from URL
    xhr.open('POST', '/favorite.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHtppRequest');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            var result = xhr.responseText;
            //console.log('Result: ' + result);
            if(result == 'color') {
                parent.classList.remove("favorite");
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send("door=" + door_param + "&color=" + parent.id); //This is parsed by php and put into a $_session
   //console.log("door=" + door_param + "&uncolor=" + parent.id);


 }   

function sbfSwitch(){ // should only be run if trying to add 1 more item and we already have 3 items in the session
        SBF1.style.display = "none";
        SBF2.style.display = "block";
        alert('Please delete one of the doors in the side menu, before adding  anymore. There is a MAX of 3 Doors that you can favorite.');
        getFavorites();
}
```

Comment: `how to do this with the ".then" option in JavaScript` - well, you aren't using Promises, and there's absolutely no `.then` in the code you posted ... `.then` is not a *javascript option*, it's a method of a `Promise`

Comment: Okay, so how could i write it with a promise?

Comment: try using `fetch` instead :p

Comment: failing that, your best bet is to write some code to "wrap" xmlhttprequest in a promise

Comment: couldn't answer with code block so wrote it in answers, was trying out your suggest and would like some suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `fetch` your first two functions would be

```
function favoriteNr() {
    var body = new FormData();
    body.append('door', gup('name'));
    return fetch('/nr_check.php', { 
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHtppRequest'
        }),
        body: body
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network status ' + response.status + ':' + response.statusText)
        }
        return response.text();
    })

function favorite() {
    var parent = this.parentElement;
    var body = new FormData();
    body.append('door', gup('name'));
    body.append('color', parent.id);
    return fetch('/favorite.php', { 
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHtppRequest'
        }),
        body: body
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network status ' + response.status + ':' + response.statusText)
        }
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        if(result == 'color') {
            parent.classList.remove("favorite");
        }
    });
}

favoriteNr()
.then(result) {
    var n = parseInt(result);
    if (n >=0 && n <=2) {
        return favorite();
    }
    sbfSwitch();
}
```

Comment: They are still separate functions now, right? so if I called favorite I would only get the result of favorite. that is why I want favorite to know the result of favoriteNr(). This would prevent it from just serving data to my php

Comment: Yes ... they are ... as per your code. Let me read the question again, I must've missed something important

Comment: One thing to note about `fetch` - I don't think it sends cookies in the request

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was looking at my own question this morning and said why am I doing it this way? php can solve this much cleaner and less redundant. I do like the "then/fetch" stuff but its not that widely supported yet. made a small change to my functions if(result == 'door') {
      parent.classList.add("favorite");
     } if(result >= 3) {
                        sbfSwitch();
                    }

Comment: and with the result from php javascript does the job i want

Answer (score 0):

So been looking into some example fetch code, (still not completely cleaner on everything) but would that work out to something like this then?

```
var request = new Request('/nr_check.php',{
 method: 'POST',
 mode: 'cors', //what is this and do i need it?
 redirect: 'follow',// same
 headers: new Headers({
     'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
     'X-Requested-With', 'XMLHtppRequest' //is this still necessary? 
 })
});

 xhr.send("door=" + door_param); // where those this go now?

 fetch(request).then(function(favorite){
     if(request.result <= 3){
        favorite();
     } else {
          sbfSwitch();
     }
 });
```

Comment: `where those this go now` ... in the Request object `body` property

Comment: `mode: cors` - is your request cross origin?

Comment: `'Content-Type': 'text/plain'` - why? use your original content

Comment: Thx for all that info, will check it out further tomorrow. im new to JavaScript and before u mentioned fetch i hadnt heard of it so im really just trying with what i can find now. i mostly solve my stuff with php or css.

Comment: have you looked at the answer I posted? Does it work (I'm only 90% confident :p )

Comment: looking over your functions, so should i send back now just true or false?

Comment: im not at work now so cant check. will do first thing tomorrow morning.